# Non ho mai detto che il tuo seno sia/fosse brutto

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood, tenses

Sono italiano e parlo italiano dalla nascita, ma a volte i congiuntivi sono difficili anche per noi.
Nella traduzione italiana di una commedia di Feydeau, ho trovato questa frase:

> Non ho mai detto che il tuo seno sia brutto.

Istintivamente, io avrei detto: "Non ho mai detto che il tuo seno FOSSE brutto", ma non saprei spiegare perché.

Mi chiarite, per favore, quale forma è giusta e perché?

Comment: Direi che sia un fatto di tempi (sia verbali che cronologici): “che sia brutto” = lo è sempre; “che fosse brutto” = lo era allora, quando ne parlammo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La tua intuizione è corretta: se guardiamo la tabella a pagina 390 del libro *Italiano* di Serianni, vediamo che quando la reggente è al passato prossimo il tempo corretto per esprimere la contemporaneità è il congiuntivo imperfetto. Per cui, a seguire le regole strettamente, *fosse* è più corretto di *sia*.

Tuttavia è forse il caso di precisare che queste regole non sono così rigide come talvolta le grammatiche le fanno sembrare. Sempre dal libro di Serianni, XIV.58.c:

> Talvolta si può avere un tempo diverso da quello atteso per effetto di un particolare «punto di vista» del parlante. Si vedano i seguenti esempi (da DARDANO-TRIFONE 1985: 312): «ho temuto che quella notizia ti *potesse* dispiacere» (col normale imperfetto congiuntivo richiesto
> dalla contemporaneità nel passato); «ho temuto che questa notizia ti *possa* dispiacere» (il congiuntivo presente si deve all’attualità del fatto, marcata «anche attraverso l’uso del pronome dimostrativo *questa* invece di *quella*»).

Vale a dire, in questo caso l'uso del congiuntivo presente serve a marcare il fatto che lo stato del seno in questione è ancora oggetto di (una molto delicata!) discussione.